# Issues with 'Split Features' in QGIS 2.18.2 - splitting polygons with holes

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, splitting

I am trying to split polygons using the 'Split Features' tool. This works for most polygons except for the ones that consist of a full circle such as the selected polygon in the snapshot below:

[image]

I also tried using 'Split selected features with selected line from another layer'. This does not work either.

Comment: What happens if you try to split it? Does an error message pop up and if so, what is the message?

Comment: There's no error message. I place the line by left clicking twice, when I then right-click the red line disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this issue the polygon had to be split at two places simultaneously. i.e. when using 'Split Features' make sure that the line drawn intersects the polygon twice.